# UI freezed while calling REST API from background?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

In my application I have a REST API call for sending data to server,while calling the API it will freezed my UI.

```
try
    {
                            string url = GlobalVariables.ServiceUrl + "Buyer/Order/CreateBuyer?sellerUserName=" + System.Uri.EscapeDataString(GlobalVariables.SellerUsername);
                            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                            StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            Response responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result);
                            if (responseData.Status == 0)
                            {
                               // DependencyService.Get<IFClass>().ShortAlert("Buyer Sync Failed.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().CreatedDeleteBuyersFromLocal(data.Id);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
```

How to solve this?

Comment: I'd first try to figure out which line of code is causing the freeze.  Simply debugging line by line would give you a sense of how long each line takes (and may point to the issue).  There are some async lines in there, so I would focus on the lines that aren't async, but are doing IO work (serialization/deserialization/CreatedDeleteBuyersFromLocal/etc).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with xamarin but such calls like sql queries,web service call etc. should be done in a seperate thread.Await may not be a solution for this.
Try using a BackgroundWorker or Thread instead.